# Bypassing Gson number parser implementation

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am parsing JSON in my Android application using Gson. Say I want to parse this json:

```
{
    "foo": 01
}
```

Now, according to the Json spec [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf):

> A number is represented in base 10 with no superfluous leading zero [...]

Meaning that the json above in **invalid**. Unfortunately Gson for some reason does not implement this, and gives me `foo` as the `String` `"01"`. When parsing, I cannot tell if the original value was a string, or just a badly formatted number.

When I receive the JsonPrimitive from `foo`, the method `isString` returns true. It should throw a `JsonSyntaxException`.

I have tried gson's custom deserialization, but no luck there. I've searched everywhere on the web, and even went through the Gson's project open issues, but couldn't find nothing about this.

Is there a way to detect this type of wrong syntax?

#### Edit

This is the code that worked for me:

```
private class Bar implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("foo")
    private String foo;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{\"foo\" : 01}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Bar bar = gson.getAdapter(Bar.class).fromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: If you know which of your json keys have their value as an integer, then it's better to get that value as an int. For example,

    JsonElement ele = obj.get("foo");
       System.out.println(ele.getAsInt());

would print `'1'`.

Yes, but generally speaking most of the times you don't want to have this extra checks specifically for some of the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gson`, by default, parses in lenient mode. You can use

```
gson.getAdapter(type).fromJson(json);
```

to parse in strict mode. For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{\"value\" : 01}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    System.out.println(gson.getAdapter(Value.class).fromJson(json));
}

static class Value {
    Integer value;

    public String toString() {
        return "" + value;
    }
}
```

throws

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:589)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:234)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:231)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJson(TypeAdapter.java:256)
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJson(TypeAdapter.java:269)
    at com.example.Example.main(Example.java:21)
```

This is discussed [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=422).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but if I wanted `foo` to be a String, it will not throw any Exception.

Comment: @Luke What is `foo` in my example?

Comment: Please, see the edit in my answer. In your example, if value was a String it would not throw exceptions

Comment: @Luke If you are referring to the `Integer value` field, changing it to `String value` causes an exception as well.

Comment: You are correct. But I still cannot reproduce this in the code I provided :/

Comment: @luke You are using the `Gson` instance. I am using the `TypeAdapter`.